# Azure NetX Duo only provides the driver for LAN8742 compatible Ethernet PHYs. How can I manage other Ethernet PHYs?

Tags: stm32, rtos, stm32cubemx, threadx, ethernet-phy

I'm developing an application for STM32F4 with Azure RTOS Netx Duo. In particular I'm trying to adapt the example **Nx_TCP_Echo_Server** application for my board where is present the Ethernet Phy ADIN1200 produced by Analog Devices.

### Note about example `Nx_TCP_Echo_Server`

The **Nx_TCP_Echo_Server** example application has been made for a STM32F429ZI-NUCLEO demo board ([code of Nx_TCP_Echo_Server](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/x-cube-azrtos-f4/tree/main/Projects/STM32F429ZI-Nucleo/Applications/NetXDuo/Nx_TCP_Echo_Server) on github).
In the demo board STM32F429ZI-NUCLEO the Ethernet Phy is compatible with the **lan8742** driver (see the [lan8742 driver code](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32-lan8742) on GitHub). Unfortunately the Ethernet PHY ADIN1200 present on my board is not compatible with that driver.

I have noted that the sixth parameter of the function `nx_ip_create()` is the pointer function `nx_stm32_eth_driver`.
This pointer function points to **lan8742** driver.
Below I show the invocation of the function `nx_ip_create()` present in the file `app_netxduo.c` ([code of app_netxduo.c](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/x-cube-azrtos-f4/blob/main/Projects/STM32F429ZI-Nucleo/Applications/NetXDuo/Nx_TCP_Echo_Server/NetXDuo/App/app_netxduo.c)) of the Nx_TCP_Echo_Server example application:

```
/* Create the main NX_IP instance */
  ret = nx_ip_create(&IpInstance, "Main Ip instance", NULL_ADDRESS, NULL_ADDRESS, &AppPool, nx_stm32_eth_driver,
                     pointer, 2 * DEFAULT_MEMORY_SIZE, DEFAULT_PRIORITY);
```

The [documentation of NetX Duo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/rtos/netx-duo/chapter5) reports the following info:

> The NX_IP structure contains everything to manage a single IP instance. This includes general TCP/IP protocol information as well as **the application-specific physical network driver's entry routine. The driver's entry routine is defined during the nx_ip_create service.** Additional devices may be added to the IP instance via the nx_ip_interface_attach service.

### My development environment

My development environment is composed by:

- STM32CubeMX version 6.7.0
- In the STM32CubeMX I have installed the Package STM32F4 version 1.27.1
- To use ThreadX I have added to CubeMX the software pack X-CUBE-AZRTOS-F4 version 1.1.0

By the previous environment I can find only the driver for LAN8742.

### My question

How can I find other Ethernet PHY drivers for **NetX Duo** other than the one for lan8742?

---

**EDIT**

I have found [this driver for ADIN1200](https://www.oryx-embedded.com/doc/adin1200__driver_8c_source.html) but it is very far from the driver `lan8742.c` provided by my development tool (see the [code of lan8742](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32-lan8742)).
In fact the API of the 2 drivers are very different; for example NetX Duo (and before it: `LwIP`) needs a function like `LAN8742_RegisterBusIO()` (present in the LAN8742 driver) to init a structure with pointer functions useful to write and read registers of the Ethernet PHY, but in [this driver](https://www.oryx-embedded.com/doc/adin1200__driver_8c_source.html) this function and its data structures are not present.

Comment: You try to do cargo-cult programming. The driver will help understand how the chip (but it will not replace the documentation) works. Having this knowledge you can port it to threadx.

Answer (score 1):

You can find different phy drivers from https://github.com/azure-rtos/samples.

- mimxrt1060：KSZ8081RNB
- same54：KSZ8091RNA
- stm32f746：LAN8742A-CZ-TR
- rx65n rsk：DP83620SQE

For others, you will need to develop the driver by yourself, based on existing ones.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to follow your indication as soon as possible.. Now I have to do an other task. My PHY is ADIN1200 so from Analog Device. I hope that one of the driver present in your link is suited for it.

Comment: I'm looking for the driver in the samples. I have downloaded some of the ZIP files but I can't find the driver code.. Are you sure that in the example is present the code of the Ethernet PHY driver. For example in the example for STMicroelectronics (`Azure_RTOS_6.2_Renesas_CK_RX65N_e2studio_CCRX_Sample_2022_12_28.zip`) I can't find the driver for LAN8742A-CZ-TR! Could you help me to find the code (if you can update your answer).

Comment: Take [STM32F746](https://github.com/azure-rtos/samples/releases/download/v6.1_rel/Azure_RTOS_6.1_STM32F746G-DISCO_IAR_Samples_2021_11_03.zip) for example, the logic of phy is mixed in HAL APIs. You can find phy initialization in stm32f7xx_hal_eth.c. In latest network driver, ST has separate the phy  driver. You can take a look at the [nx_stm32_phy_driver.c](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/x-cube-azrtos-h7/blob/main/Middlewares/ST/netxduo/common/drivers/ethernet/lan8742/nx_stm32_phy_driver.c).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to put all the info together and write a driver for the PHY. ADIN1200.